# VBA Extracting data from textbox

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to extract partial information from a list, for which the information comes in a specific format (this list doesn't come in a spreadsheet):

```
A BUYS: PRODUCT @ 85 / B SELLS
B BUYS: PRODUCT @ 500 / C SELLS
B BUYS: PRODUCT @ 200 / A SELLS
```

If I paste the entire list into a textbox, is it possible to extract only part of the data from the textbox?

For the first line of the list "A BUYS: PRODUCT @ 85 / B SELLS", I would like to separate: "A" ; "Product" ; "85" ; "B", and put them into different cells in the same row.

Any help would be really appreciated. Or maybe you have a simpler method to achieve this?

Comment: you could try with `Text-To-Column` which is available in Ribbon>>Data. However, some additional action will be required.

Answer (score 0):

Something like below? either that or you could try text to columns

```
temp = split("A BUYS: PRODUCT @ 85 / B SELLS"," ")
A = temp(0)
Product = temp(2)
qty = temp(4)
B = temp(6)
```

Comment: Thanks 99moorem that would do as well

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to iterate through the list, perhaps something like the below?

```
Sub splitMyList()

    Dim iRow As Integer
    iRow = 1

    Do While Cells( iRow, 1) <> ""
        temp = Split( Cells( iRow, 1 ), " ")
        Cells( iRow, 2 ) = temp(0)
        Cells( iRow, 3 ) = temp(2)
        Cells( iRow, 4 ) = temp(4)
        Cells( iRow, 5 ) = temp(6)

        iRow = iRow + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

This assumes you pasted your list in column A starting on row 1. Just change the figures if needed. Hope this helps